# Dividing arbitrary large numbers stored in char arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, division

A part of my home assignment requires dividing large integers that are so long I can only store them in character arrays. Both the divident and the divisor can be one to thousands of digits long, therefore the result of the division has to be stored in a char array too, because it can be very lengthy as well. I want to store one digit per index.

I'm trying to use repeated subtractions until the divident is smaller than the divisor and counting the turns. The worst case is when the divisor is 2, so I have to allocate 'length of divident / 2' amount of memory for the counter array.

I already have the *subtraction*, the *getLength* and the *lengthCompare* function implemented and they're functioning fine. Here is what I've done so far:

```
char *division(char *divident, char *divisor, int len_divident, int len_divisor)
{
    if (divident == NULL || divisor == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    char *cnt = (char*)malloc((len_divident/ 2) * sizeof(char));
    char *res = subtraction(divident, divisor, len_divident, len_divisor);
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        res = subtraction(res, divisor, getLength(res), len_divisor);

        if (cnt[i] == 9)
        {
            i++;
        }

        cnt[i]++;

    } while (lengthCompare(res, divisor) == 1 || lengthCompare(res, divisor) == 0);
    
    cnt->digits[i + 1] = '\0';
    return cnt;
}
```

The *lengthCompare* function returns 1 if the first parameter is longer then the second or 2 if the second one is longer and 0 if their length is equal.

This code doesn't work - every time I compile I get "ERROR - Not enough space" message.
Edit: to be specific, it's an exception from the subtraction function:
*Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.
result was 0x1110112.*

Please note that I'm a beginner to C and this is probably not the best method to do what I want but I couldn't think of better.

I much appreciate any cricitism and suggestion!

Edit: `n` and `a` renamed to divident and divisor.

Comment: What is the exact error, and is it being generated by your code or is it a C error?  If it's being generated by your code, we probably need to see where it's coming form as well.

Comment: Curious, why the call the _dividend_ and _divisor_ `n` and `a`?  How about `dividend, divisor` or maybe `a,b` or `top, bottom`?

Comment: @Donnie it's a C error, I added the exception I get. @chux the function is a part of a primality test where I call these numbers `n` and `a` but I already renamed them in the question. Thanks. Also, number `a` is generated and it can't be zero.

Comment: FYI, you are more than likely leaking memory as well with your malloc - unless you are some sort of means of freeing it elsewhere.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I free `cnt` where I call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The worst case is ... , so I have to allocate 'length of divident / 2' amount of memory for the counter array.

Not quite, the worst case is closer to a subtraction.

Code is not allocating enough memory.

```
char *cnt = (char*)malloc((len_divident / 2) * sizeof(char));  // Bad
```

---

After insuring the *divisor*,  represents a value without leading zeros ...

```
while (len_divisor > 0 && divisor == '0') {
  len_divisor--;
  divisor++;
}
```

...., the space needed does not exceed:

```
// As it looks like code is using strings
#define SPACE_FOR NULL_CHARACTER 1

size_t length = 1 + SPACE_FOR NULL_CHARACTER;
if (len_dividend > _len_divisor) {
  length = len_dividend - len_divisor + 1 + SPACE_FOR NULL_CHARACTER;
}
```

No need in C for the cast.  If one wants to scale by the type of the pointer, better to use `sizeof *pointer *` then `* sizeof(type)`.   It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
char *cnt = malloc(sizeof *cnt * length);
```

---

Robust code would check for allocation success.

```
if (cnt == NULL) {
  Handle_OutOfMemory_Somehow();
}
```